# Stream applications from Windows

Tags: ssh, x11, windows, xming

How can I get windowing like XMing but the other way around -- to have a Windows window in a Linux graphical environment?

---

I want to do an SSH like, wheter it comes from a VM or a distant computer, just have his apps running in Linux graphical environment

I want to run apps that Wine can't run

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details what you want to do. Do you mean remote desktop access? (see rdesktop, vnc, teamviewer, anydesk...)

Comment: I want to do an SSH like, wheter it comes from a VM or a distant computer, just have his apps running in Linux graphical environment

Comment: Done ~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: rdp is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking for the feature called "[RemoteApp](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/RemoteApp)" as avaliable in FreeRDP:

```
xfreerdp /u:user /d:domain /p:password /app:"||calc" /v:server
```